# Transfer data from linux to fpga and inversely?

Tags: linux, fpga

I have booted a ubuntu on a ZedBoard. I want to transfer data between fpga and linux. For example, I want to write or read a register from linux. What is best way for doing it? I have not any idea.
Thanx.

Comment: You mean [ZedBoard](http://www.zedboard.org/), right?

Comment: Great. I have nothing but respect for people who boot Linux on their [motorized skateboards](http://www.zboardshop.com/) but was somewhat surprised about the FPGA.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to specifically say what you want to do, for example. if you want to access the IO signals on the FPGA, you need to first add the GPIO module to your system, synthesize and implement it.

Then you use the **Linux GPIO Driver** to access the port as it is explained in this page:

[Linux GPIO Driver](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Linux+GPIO+Driver)

> The GPIO driver fits in the Linux GPIO framework which is not a char
>   mode driver. Yet it does provide access to the GPIO by user space
>   through the sysfs filesystem. This allows each GPIO signal to be read
>   and written in similar manner to a char mode device. The interface is
>   somewhat documented in the kernel tree at Documentation/gpio.txt. The
>   following text is aimed to augment, not replace the existing
>   documentation.

For other, more complex interfaces you need to create your own driver or use one of the drivers that are available and modify it to fit your needs.